# Android hindi to english conversion without internet connection

Tags: android, translation, transliteration

In my android app, I want to convert hindi text to english without doing the actual translation (want to transliterate). And I want to do it without actually using the internet connection. I have found ways but they all require querying an end point. Is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: That is called [**transliteration**](http://www.omniglot.com/writing/hindi.htm) and using a table with some special case markers that you then handle would be relative easy. As English is not really phonetical, the IPA between square brackets might be used for prononciation by the mobile.

Comment: okay. But is there something that google already provides for offline support or would I have create a manual mapping, table, myself ?